# Filter same level object values in loop data weave - Mule 3.7

Tags: mule, dataweave

I am trying to filter same level object values in the payload in Dataweave. I was able to loop through but it does not produce the expected output. 
Sample Payload:

```
{
    "root": {
        "createItem": {
            "itemInfo": {
                "lines": [{
                    "lineIdentifier": "4",
                    "Attributes": "Test1",
                    "partNumber": "QZRB"
                }, {
                    "lineIdentifier": "10",
                    "Attributes": "Test3",
                    "partNumber": "QPR1"
                }, {
                    "lineIdentifier": "12",
                    "Attributes": "Test4",
                    "partNumber": "QHT2"
                }]
            }
        },
        "ItemResponse": {
            "lines": [{
                "lineIdentifier": 4,
                "itemName": "QZRB",
                "status": "FAILED"
            }, {
                "lineIdentifier": 10,
                "itemName": "QPR1",
                "status": "COMPLETE"
            }, {
                "lineIdentifier": 12,
                "itemName": "QHT2",
                "status": "COMPLETE"
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Expected Output:

```
{
    "root": {
        "createItem": {
            "itemInfo": {
                "lines": [ {
                    "lineIdentifier": "10",
                    "Attributes": "Test3",
                    "partNumber": "QPR1"
                }, {
                    "lineIdentifier": "12",
                    "Attributes": "Test4",
                    "partNumber": "QHT2"
                }]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's what I am doing:

```
{
    root: {
        (payload.root.createItem.itemInfo.lines map ((respLines, indexOfRespLines) -> {
        items:payload.root.ItemResponse.lines filter ($.itemName == respLines.partNumber and $.status =='COMPLETE') map 
        {
            item: $.itemName,
         attributes: respLines.Attributes
         }

        }

        )
        )
    }
}
```

How do I achieve this?

Thanks, 
ROA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
%var completedLines = payload.root.ItemResponse.lines filter $.status == 'COMPLETE' map $.lineIdentifier as :string
---
{
    root: {
        createItem: {
            itemInfo: {
                lines: payload.root.createItem.itemInfo.lines filter (completedLines contains $.lineIdentifier)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

pay attention to `as :string` in `completedLines`, because the `lineIdentifier` in `ItemResponse` is a number, while in `itemInfo` it is a string.

Comment: Hi Yevgeniy, Thanks for the response. Below is the response that I am getting: {
  "root": {
    "foo": [
      10,
      12
    ],
    "createItem": {
      "itemInfo": {
        "lines": [
          
        ]
      }
    }
  }
} It seems that the inner filter does not seem to get the required data.

Comment: i assume your input data looks different then in your initial question. most probably lineIdentifier are not strings but numbers. Then you have to remove the `as :string`. BTW: i forgot to remove foo :)

Comment: Hi Yevgeniy, Sorry.They are strings. Still it does not work. Any pointers?

Comment: @ROA i am afraid you will have to provide more details, because for me the above dataweave works as expected. can you upload a sample mule-application to github?